# Django/HTML form input alignment

Tags: html, css, django, web, alignment

I'm trying to make something very simple. What I have is currently this:
[image: Browser Preview]

The current code is this:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<style>
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<div class='center'>
    <form action='.' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
        <div align="right">
            <input type="text" name='title' placeholder='Food title'/>
        </div>
        <div align='left'>
            <input type="text" name='q' placeholder='Search Image'/>
            <input type="submit" value='Search!'/> 
        </div>
        {% for image in images %}
            <img src="{% static 'img/search/' %}{{ image }}", alt=""/>
            <input type="radio" name="imageRadio" value={{image}}/>
            </br>
        {% endfor %}
            <input type="submit" value='Go!'/>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

My issue is, no matter what I try, I can't get the Food title input and the search bar to line up. I would like to have them spaced apart but on the same horizontal line and not one slightly above the other.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this in a few ways (of course).  You can use float (not the best idea), you can consider using FlexBox.  Flexbox is highly supported nowadays.

Example

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<style>
    .center {
      margin: auto;
      width: 50%;
      border: 3px solid green;
      padding: 10px;
    }
    .inputs {
        display: flex;
        justify-content: space-between;
    }
</style>

<div class='center'>
    <form action='.' method='POST'> {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="inputs">
            <div>
                <input type="text" name='title' placeholder='Food title'/>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input type="text" name='q' placeholder='Search Image'/>
                <input type="submit" value='Search!'> 
            </div>
        </div>
        {% for image in images %}
            <img src="{% static 'img/search/' %}{{ image }}", alt=""/>
            <input type="radio" id=image name="gender" value="male">
            </br>
        {% endfor %}
        <input type="submit" value='Go!'>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to basic HTML and CSS. You have your `input`s in two separate `div`s, which are block-level elements, meaning that they will each take up their own "row" on the page. Although we could simply change the `display` of both of these `div`s, I'll just skip to the best practice, and suggest that you put the `input`s into a shared `div`, and give them a `display` of `flex`, then adjust the "spacing" with `justify-content`, as in:

```html
<style>
.center {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  border: 3px solid green;
  padding: 10px;
}
.my-inputs {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
</style>


<div class="my-inputs">
    <input type="text" name='title' placeholder='Food title'/>
    <input type="text" name='q' placeholder='Search Image'/>
    <input type="submit" value='Search!'/>
</div>
```